# Cache using ImagePng (PHP) via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, caching

I should create a dynamic PNG file and upload it to the server via AJAX, and return the URL of the file.

However, the image is always the same.

The JS code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url:    "ajax/genPOCode.php",
    data:   "comp=" + competicio,
    type:   "GET",
    success: function ( result )
    {
        window.prompt ( result );
    }
});
```

The code of the AJAX file is:

```
$time = time();
clearstatcache();
$nas = file_get_contents ( "http://www.example.com/playoffsimg2.php?upload=" . $time . "&leagueid=" . $_GET['comp'] . "&day=FINAL" );
echo utf8_encode ( "http://www.example.com/images/brackets/" . $time . "-" . $_GET['comp'] . ".png" );
```

And the PHP code of the file playoffsimg2.php is:

```
Line 1: header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
Line 2: header ( "Content-Type: image/png" );
Line 466: imagepng ( $image, "images/brackets/" . $_GET['upload'] . "-" . $_GET['leagueid'] . ".png" );
Line 467: imagedestroy ( $image );
```

I think it's a trouble related with cache, because when I call the file http://www.example.com/playoffsimg2.php from the browser, it works right.

Comment: Would be better if you post your js code here.